# cURL doesn't work when served by Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, bind, curl

Getting "Cannot resolve host" as a cURL error within a PHP script using a hostname. IPv4s work fine though.

Running cURL at a hostname via command line works.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the network daemon wasn't full initialized before httpd started. Therefore causing Apache to have incorrect DNS information.

Simply restarting named (bind) effectively refreshes the DNS cache so that Apache can resolve hostnames. It may be prudent to move httpd farther back in the run levels to give the network daemon to complete initialization before Apache starts.

Note: this also effects PHP functions like gethostbyname().